# Deploy allow unauthenticated GCP functions with serverless

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

Is there a parameter to add in `serverless.yml` to deploy GCP functions (`Go`) the same way it can be done by adding `--allow-unauthenticated` to `gcloud deploy` command?

Can't find any information about this in the [serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's not possible. Serverless product uses the Cloud Functions API to deploy te Cloud Functions. To set the allow-unauthenticated, you need to use the IAM API to add the `cloudfunctions.invoker` role to `allUsers`.

gcloud CLI offers a convenient way to package the both API call in a single command line, but external tool need to implement the same extra effort to achieve that. That's why, I'm pretty sure that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by using hooks. You need to add custom > scripts to serverless.yml

(Note: This should work, given that the service account that you are using have the proper access)

like this:

```
custom:
  scripts:
        commands:
            make-public-function: gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-${opt:opt.function, "functionName"} --member="allUsers" --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" --project=${self:provider.project} --region=${self:provider.region} | xargs echo

        hooks:   
            'after:deploy:deploy': npx sls make-public-function --stage ${self:provider.stage}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Don't forget to install the plugin serverless-plugin-scripts by running "npm install --save serverless-plugin-scripts".